# Android Softkeyboard/Virtual keyboard Gravity/ display in center

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have created virtual keyboard. Its showning bottom of the screen.I want to display my keyboard near the EditText without adjust screen size  & not bottom of the screen.

For example I have list of product , that list contain EditText.When User click on that EditText that virtual keyboard should display left/right of EditText. IS it possible to do this?

Second question is: How we can change android keyboard gravity or layout width pragmatically? is it possible to change it?

Comment: If you find a solution to this, please post it!

Comment: I couldn't find the solution for this. I did using popupwindow numeric pad like calculator.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to change it but not easily.

You can use this:

```
    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

As a view which will contain your keyboard. You must then, in your Activity, create a `Keyboard` object to attach to it, you can either create your own using xml (as I have below) or there are several ways to instantiate `LatinIME` or other classes which extend `Keyboard` as a standard system keyboard.

```
Keyboard mKeyboard = new Keyboard(context, R.xml.function);
mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboard);
```

I could write a whole article on how to use your own keyboard effectively but hopefully this will give you enough of a clue to be able to look up tutorials on your own.

This [example](https://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example) should give you alot of help though.

Good luck!

Comment: But how to change gravity?