# How to pop up android keyboard to the extreme right in edittext?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I am using an edittext and my app is in landscape mode .
My Edittext is on right side of the Screen . when i click on edittext then the keyboard that pops up in the middle gives bad UX to user edit text on right side and keyboard in the middle . is there anyway i can keep it at the right end.
[image]

Comment: A custom keyboard would likely help but it's not easy

https://stackoverflow.com/q/7671916/6024687

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to align the keyboard to the right:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
IBinder winToken = editText.getWindowToken();

//Align keyboard to right of screen
WindowManager.LayoutParams window_params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
   
window_params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
window_params.x = 0;
window_params.y = 0;
window_params.token = winToken;

//Add alignment to keyboard
getWindowManager().addView(YOUR_KEYBOARD_VIEW, window_params);
```

Gravity.RIGHT is used to align to the right and Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL is used to align it to the vertical center. You can use the window_params.x and window_params.y parameters to align the keyboard in a custom way.